# Nginx restart fails: Simple reverse proxy config

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to setup nginx gunicorn flask setup, using this guide. https://realpython.com/blog/python/kickstarting-flask-on-ubuntu-setup-and-deployment/

A simple reverse proxy nginx to gunicorn, which eventually talks to flask app.

This is my nginx config at /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask-project

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
    location /static {
        alias  /home/www/flask_project/static/;
    }
}
```

Nginx restart fails

Output of this command

```
sudo nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask_project
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask_project:1
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask_project test failed
```

Any pointers whats going on?

Comment: How does your `nginx.conf` look like?

Comment: Can you show the nginx.conf file?

Answer (score 0):

Yup. You're just trying to hard. You should issue `nging -t`, or `nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (the latter one is redundant, because it's the same thing as the first), because */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flask-project* just isn't a full nginx configuration file, it's simply it's piece, which misses most vital parts of the config, starting (but not limited to) with `http {}`.

Comment: i see, but not sure why nginx restart fails. any idea?

Comment: You didn't provide any output from restart. Would be nice to see it. Either from direct `nginx -s reload` or from the error log.